# Which setting is causing my floating shelf toolbar in Maya to be a vertical window?

Tags: window, toolbar, maya

I like to have my shelf bar floating. But for some reason if during a session I end up closing the shelf window while its floating and I reopen it via a hotkey, the shelf window will have a vertical tab bar, as shown in these examples:

[image: Vertical window]
[image: Vertical tab bar]

The only fix I have managed to find is resetting the workspace, but that is only temporary, if I end up closing the floating shelf I am once again beset and besieged by this vertical tab bar.